# Sql select query confusion when passing getdate() & its value to where condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a Employee table like below

```
ID    Name     Mobile      Ondate                   Address
1     Ankit    1234567895  2016-11-08 10:10:04.540  abc
2     Amit     4521545258  2016-11-08 11:10:04.540  bcd
3     Amit2    7541258562  2016-11-08 12:10:04.540  gfd
```

Now i write select query like below then it gives all records of Employee table

```
select * from Employee where convert(date,ondate)='2016-11-08 12:10:04.540'
```

but when i pass `getdate()` direct in where condition then it gives empty

```
select * from Employee where convert(date,ondate)=getdate()
```

while `select getdate()` result is `2016-11-08 12:10:04.540`

so please give proper reason about it.

Comment: have you try to convert date to spesific format??

Comment: Dear @Denny i have executed both same query without converting and the first one gives proper result while the second one gives empty

Comment: What is data type of `Ondate` column?

Comment: try this **select * from Employee where convert(varchar(20),ondate,113)=convert(varchar(20),getdate(),113)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is [data type precedence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms190309.aspx) at work. In your first query, in the `WHERE` clause you have a `date` on one side of a comparison and a `varchar` on the other. `date` wins, your string is converted to a `date`, the time is ignored and every row matches.

In your second query, you have a `date` on one side of the comparison and a `datetime` on the other side. `datetime` wins, the `date` is converted (back) into a `datetime`, and the datetimes don't match on their time components.

If you want to select values for today, use something like:

```
select * from Employee
where ondate >= DATEADD(day,DATEDIFF(day,0,GETDATE()),0) and
ondate < DATEADD(day,DATEDIFF(day,0,GETDATE()),1)
```

Where the `DATEADD`/`DATEDIFF` expressions are effectively computing "midnight at the start of today" and "midnight at the start of tomorrow". Both expressions will be computed once, and any index on the `ondate` column can then be used, if one exists, and we avoid excessively transforming column data.

Comment: I do like your explanation far better than other answers, however I think their solution is a bit more readable.

Comment: @Aquillo - I agree that the `DATEADD`/`DATEDIFF` pattern can look a bit daunting to begin with. However, if you start using it, you'll find it's broadly applicable in a number of situations and it soon becomes practically invisible. (E.g. the same type of pattern can be used to compute "the start of this/next month", etc)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever You're right about using `DATEDIFF`, no question there. After further examining I do like the approach of not mutating the `ondate` column to preserve any indexes, even though it makes the query a bit harder to read.

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
select * from Employee where convert(date,ondate)=Convert(date,getdate())
```

Comment: Dear read question carefully i m asking for reason not for query result but ok thanks for reply

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * from Employee where DATEDIFF(DAY,Ondate,'2016-11-08 10:10:04.540') = 0
```

OR
    SELECT * from Employee where DATEDIFF(DAY,Ondate,GETDATE()) = 0

Comment: Dear read question carefully i m asking for reason not for query result but ok thanks for reply